# Контейнер для констант

Tags: c++

Есть список UnicodeString констант и соответствующий ему список целочисленных констант:

```
const UnicodeString ERR = L"Error";
const UnicodeString READY = L"Ready";
...
const int S_ERR = 0;
const int S_READY = 1;
...
```

Не знаю, какой контейнер для хранения и удобной работы с этими данными использовать. Если использовать их отдельно, то получается крайне неудобно с ними работать, когда надо получать строку в зависимости от состояния и подобные действия:

```
switch (Status) {
case S_ERR: 
return ERR;
...
}
```

Какой контейнер можно использовать для этого? Очень важен ответ, часто использую такого рода логику.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Раз у Вас есть ассоциативное отношение, то сам собой напрашивается ассоциативный контейнер, а именно: `std::unordered_map`:

```
...
const int S_ERR = 0;
const int S_READY = 1;
...
std::unordered_map<int, UnicodeString> strings;
strings.emplace(S_ERR, L"Error");
strings.emplace(S_READY, L"Ready");
...
return strings[Status];
```

Это позволяет нам не задумывать о том, в каком порядке, что хранится и не пользоваться `switch`, который только раздувает код.

Answer (score 5):

Если константы идут строго подряд - std::vector (std::array). Если с дырами - std::map

Пример с вектором ([ideone](http://ideone.com/wHWNwV))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

static constexpr array<wchar_t*,2> strs ={L"azaza",L"ololo"};

int main() {
    for(const auto i:strs)
    {
        wcout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

А для локализации существует PoEdit и связанный с ним фреймворк.

Comment: А как можно объявить вектор констант?

Comment: @T2skler  - смотрите ответ

Comment: А зачем `static` у `strs`?

Comment: @ixSci, здесь `static`-объявление переменной ограничивает область её видимости в пределах данной единицы трансляции (в общем случае, в пределах данного файла)

Comment: @aleks.andr, это избыточно для `const` и `constexpr` они по умолчанию имеют internal linkage

Comment: @ixSci, Вероятно так, я с подробностями стандарта тут не знаком. Часто встречал `static` использовавшийся в legacy-коде, как аналог безымянного `namespace { var ... ; }`

Comment: @aleks.andr, ну да, для неконстантных объектов это действительно может быть полезно.

Answer (score 4):

Применение контейнеров в данном простом случае избыточно.

Для решения описанной вами задачи, я определяю перечисление с числовыми константами и пишу функцию которая выполняет сопоставление чисел и строк. Теперь необходимо следить за этим сопоставлением. Чтобы о нем не забыть, я добавляю `assert` в функции сопоставления плюс вывожу какую-либо заметую строку. `Assert` срабатывает в отладочной сборке, а "заметная строка" в выпускной сборке. При таком подходе, за мою практику ниразу в выпускной сборке не появлялись несопоставленные константы, 100% забытых сопоставлений отлавливались на этапе отладки с помощью `assert`.

Дополнительно, обычно если значения приходят откуда-то извне из файла или из сети, я пишу функцию проверки значений на соответсвие константам.

Вот примерно такой код получается:

```
enum StatusCodes
{
     STATUS_SUCCESS
   , STATUS_WARNING
   , STATUS_ERROR
   , STATUS_CRASH
   , STATUS_UNKNOWN
};

const wchar_t * StatusCodeLabel(int code)
{
    switch(code)
    {
    case STATUS_SUCCESS: return L"OK"     ;
    case STATUS_WARNING: return L"Warning";
    case STATUS_ERROR  : return L"Error"  ;
    case STATUS_CRASH  : return L"Crash"  ;
    }
    assert(false); 
    return L"STATUS CODE WRONG!";
}

StatusCodes ValidateStatusCode(int code)
{
    switch(code)
    {
    case STATUS_SUCCESS:
    case STATUS_WARNING:
    case STATUS_ERROR  :
    case STATUS_CRASH  : return code;
    }
    assert(false); 
    return STATUS_UNKNOWN;
}
```

Такой подход наиболее дешев в сопровождении и эффективен в коде, даже когда констант очень много.

Почему-то именно про сопровождение обычно забывают. Поставте себя на место программиста который в первый раз читает код с "контейнерным" сопоставлением. Он видит контейнер, константы, строки какие-то и первые мысли у него будут что это часть какой-то прикладной логики, а не простое сопоставление строк константам. Вот так по чуть-чуть накапливается ненужная сложность.

Answer (score 0):

Это смотря для чего нужно.
Иногда из таких констант нужно генерировать `enum`'ы или функции. Тогда поможет `boost.preprocessor`. Пример из недавнего проекта:

```
#define SB_PROP_TYPES                                                   \
       /* type name, type, is pointer, is native, array length      */  \
       /* note: all non-pointer types should be listed              */  \
       /* in `sb_config_entry`.                                     */  \
       /* here, `$` is a valid pointer to `sb_config_entry`,        */  \
       /* `$$` is a `v_ptr` casted into a proper type.              */  \
        ((SB_STRING,            char,       1, 1, (strlen($$) + 1)  ))  \
        ((SB_LITERAL,           char,       1, 1, (strlen($$) + 1)  ))  \
        ((SB_INT,               int,        0, 1,                   ))  \
        ((SB_BOOL,              bool,       0, 1,                   ))  \
        ((SB_CHAR_PAIR_ARR,     sb_prop_char_pair_array, 1, 0, (1)  ))  \
        ((__SB_UNKNOWN,         int,        0, 1,                   ))

// ...

enum sb_prop_types {
#define __SB_OP(r, data, elem) (BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(5, 0, elem))
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(__SB_OP, , SB_PROP_TYPES))
#undef __SB_OP
};
```

Такая штука развернется в

```
enum sb_prop_types {
        SB_STRING, SB_LITERAL, SB_INT, SB_BOOL, SB_CHAR_PAIR_ARR, __SB_UNKNOWN
};
```

Далее, есть такой пример — выполняет роль вашего `switch` (работа со строками, так что используется много ифов, но вообще можно и `switch`):

```
static inline enum sb_prop_types prop_to_type(const char *__name) {
#define __SB_OP(r, data, elem)                                          \
        if (strcasecmp(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 0, elem), __name) == 0)   \
                return BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 2, elem);

        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(__SB_OP, _, SB_PROPS)

#undef __SB_OP
        return __SB_UNKNOWN;
}
```

Соответственно, развернется в большое количество ифов.